# Adding minimum Characters to Password

Tags: javascript

I have a working code to verify two passwords, but I need to add a minimum amount of characters

This is a smaller chunk of a larger project, but for the html I have:

```
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" size="30">
<label for="pass1">Password:</label>
<input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pass1" id="pass1">
<label for="pass2">Confirm Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" placeholder="password" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;">
<span id="confirmMessage" class="confirmMessage"></span>
```

As for my code I have

```
function checkPass()
{
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1');
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');
    var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
    var goodColor = "#66cc66";
    var badColor = "#ff6666";
    if(pass1.value == pass2.value)
    {
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
    }
    else
    {
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!"
    }
}
```

How do I correctly add the expression `(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/)` to my code for it to correctly execute?

Comment: Could not get what do you want, want to get the min length of the password or want to compare password for having given characters.

Comment: I want to it still validate that the passwords match, but also change it so where there is a minimum of 8 characters in the password.  It actually does not necessarily have to have certain characters.

Comment: Why don't you just add a check for length...And you are asking how to use a regular expression??

Comment: I am relatively new to coding and was not sure how to add anything that would automatically check to make sure it met the minimum lenght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before checking that the passwords match, check the length of `pass1`:

```
function checkPass()
{
    var pass1 = document.getElementById('pass1');
    var pass2 = document.getElementById('pass2');
    var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
    var goodColor = "#66cc66";
    var badColor = "#ff6666";
    // check length of pass1 here
    if(pass1.value.length < 8) {
        message.innerHTML = "Password must be at least 8 characters.";
        return;
    }
    if(pass1.value == pass2.value){
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
    }else{
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!"
    }
}
```

Comment: THANKS! I tried adding that earlier but I guess there was an error because it didnt work right.  But this is perfect thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regexp to you can do this:

```
if(pass1.value == pass2.value){
    var reg = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/;
    var res = pass1.value.match(reg);
    if (res == pass1.value) {
        pass2.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
    }
    else {
        message.innerHTML = "Password must be at least 8 letters & numbers only."
    }
}
```

This can be useful if the regex is doing something more interesting than just length checking, like confirming the passwords contains only certain characters.  The code above uses the `match()` method to see if the password value matches the regex. If it does, then the result will be the password. If it does not, the result will be empty.

Comment: That regular expression doesn't check that the password contains at least one of each group, nor does it accurately measure the length.

Comment: Ya, my point wasn't to give a final regular expression, but rather to show how you can use `match` to use whatever regexp suits your needs.